# Correct Mongoose Syntax to Query messages that user1 archived?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is this the correct query for finding all docs that user1 received where archived = true for user1?

```
var query = {
        "to.username": user1,
        "to.section.archive": true
};

Models.Message.find( query ).sort([['to.updated','descending']]).exec(function (err, messages) {
```

A sample embedded 'To' array of a messages Schema looks like this:

```
"to" : [ 
    {
        "user" : ObjectId("53b96c735f4a3902008aa019"),
        "username" : "user1",
        "updated" : ISODate("2014-07-08T06:23:43.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("53bb8e6f1e2e72fd04009dad"),
        "section" : {
            "in" : true,
            "out" : false,
            "archive" : true
        }
    }
]
```

The query should only return the doc above (user1 and archive is true)..not this next doc (archive is true, but not user1):

```
"to" : [ 
    {
        "user" : ObjectId("53b96c735f4a3902008aa019"),
        "username" : "user2",
        "updated" : ISODate("2014-07-08T06:24:42.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("53bb8e6f1e2e72fd04009dad"),
        "section" : {
            "in" : true,
            "out" : false,
            "archive" : true
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator to select the element that has **both** conditions and the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator for projection:

```
Models.Message.find(
   { 
       "to": { 
           "$elemMatch": {
              "username": "user2",
              "section.archive": true
           }
       }
   },
   { "created": 1, "message": 1, "to.$": 1 }
).sort([['to.updated','descending']]).exec(function (err, messages) {

});
```

Please note that this **only** works in matching the "first" element for projection. Also you want to "sort" on the value of the matching array element, and you cannot do that with `.find()` and the `.sort()` modifier.

If you want more than one match in the array then you need to use the aggregate method. This does more complex "filtering" and "projection" than is possible otherwise:

```
Models.Message.aggregate([

   // Match documents
   { "$match": {
        "to": { 
            "$elemMatch": {
               "username": "user2",
               "section.archive": true
            }
        }
   }},

   // Unwind to de-normalize
   { "$unwind": "$to" },

   // Match the array elements      
   { "$match": {
       "to.username": "user2",
       "to.section.archive": true
   }},

   // Group back to the original document
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "created": { "$first": "$created" },
       "message": { "$first": "$message" },
       "to": { "$push": "$to" }
   }}

   // Sort the results "correctly"
   { "$sort": { "to.updated": -1 } }

],function(err,messages) {

});
```

Or you can avoid using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by applying some logic with the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator in MongoDB 2.6 or greater. Just watching that your array contents are "truly" unique as [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) is applied to the resulting "filtered" array:

```
Models.Message.aggregate([
   { "$match": {
        "to": { 
            "$elemMatch": {
               "username": "user2",
               "section.archive": true
            }
        }
   }},
   { "$project": {
       "created": 1,
       "message": 1,
       "_id": 1,
       "to": {
           "$setDifference": [
               {
                   "$map": {
                       "input": "$to",
                       "as": "el",
                       "in": {
                           "$cond": [
                                {
                                    "$and": [
                                        { "$eq": [ "$$el.username", "user2" ] },
                                        "$$el.section.archive"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "$$el",
                                false
                            ]
                       }
                   }
               },
               [false]
           ]
       }
   }},
   { "$sort": { "to.updated": -1 } }

],function(err,messages) {

});
```

Or even using [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/):

```
Models.Messages.aggregate([
   { "$match": {
        "to": { 
            "$elemMatch": {
               "username": "user2",
               "section.archive": true
            }
        }
   }},
   { "$redact": {
       "$cond": {
           "if": {
               "$and": [
                   { "$eq": [ 
                       { "$ifNull": [ "$username", "user2" ] },
                       "user2"
                   ] },
                   { "$ifNull": [ "$section.archive", true ] }
               ]
           },
           "then": "$$DESCEND",
           "else": "$$PRUNE"
       }
   }},
   { "$sort": { "to.updated": -1 } }
],function(err,messages) {

});
```

But be careful as [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operates over all levels of the document, so your result might be unexpected.

Likely your "to" array actually only has single entries that will match though, so generally the standard projection should be fine. But here is how you do "multiple" matches in an array element with MongoDB.

Comment: What method would you recommend to return the entirety of each matching document? After testing, am using $unwind + $group aggregration, with $first accumulation for all the other fields..how does that rank in best practice?

Comment: @StackThis Just noticed that of course you want to "sort" on what would be the matching element's "updated" date. So of course you need an aggregation method to do this. What you are doing is fine, the other methods are new introductions. You might also need to project a `$min` or `$max` date value in your grouping to sort on if you are looking for multiple array matches. And possibly even sort those matches before grouping.

Comment: Appreciate the updates.. Was literally researching the $sort syntax for aggregation when your update appeared! Great to see all the methods, really grateful for your thoughtfulness and insight

Comment: @StackThis Also recently posted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24644292/2313887) which shows extracting something from an array in order to sort. A bit more involved but covers the general principles if you have multiple array matches where you need to decide on a value to sort on.

Comment: Thaks for the heads up.. Have a feature in the works that may benefit directly from this.. Thinking it through, and will take a closer look at the post.. Best,

Comment: Hey Neil, should I implement your $map/$setDifference solution for this newly realized scenario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070082/mongoose-aggregation-matching-with-if-else-conditions?